# How two move between a column layout an a tab layout?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a layout that uses columns for larger sizes and tabs at smaller sizes.  However, I'm splitting the columns into multiple tabs.

I'm close, but my issues is that the `tab-pane`s are split into two `tab-content` divs, so that when you click a tab that is in the second tab-content div, it doesn't hide the pane from the first tab-content div. Click Contacts or Options to see what I mean.

Anyway to fix this?

Or if there is another known way to accomplish this, that is great as well.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style>
    .tab-content .panel-heading {
      display: none;
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
      .tab-content > .tab-pane {
        display: block;
      }
      .tab-content .panel-heading {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs visible-xs visible-sm">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#info">Info</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#docs">Docs</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#updates">Updates</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#options">Options</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 tab-content">
        <div id="info" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane active">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Info content
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="docs" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Docs</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Document Stuff
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="updates" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Updates</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Bunch of updates
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 tab-content">
        <div id="contacts" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Contacts</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Contacts Stuff
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="options" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Options</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            The options
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing some javascript as a [tab event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events) that manually removes that `.active` class from `.tab-pane` divs.  This does also mean I need to denote where my `.tab-content` divs are at.  I added an additional class `.tn-cols-to-tabs` to identify them. You could just specify `.tab-content` if you are certain to have not other tab sets on the page.

This does mean that fades are not working correctly as supported by the tab module.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
      .tab-content .panel-heading{
        display: none;
      }

      @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
        .tab-content > .tab-pane {
          display: block;
        }
        .tab-content .panel-heading{
          display: block;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $('a[data-toggle = "tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
           $('.tn-cols-to-tabs .tab-pane.active').removeClass('active');
        })
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs visible-xs visible-sm">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#info">Info</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#docs">Docs</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#updates">Updates</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#options">Options</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 tab-content tn-cols-to-tabs">
        <div id="info" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane active">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Info content<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="docs" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Docs</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Document Stuff
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="updates" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Updates</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Bunch of updates
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4 tab-content tn-cols-to-tabs">
        <div id="contacts" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Contacts</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Contacts Stuff<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf<br/>
            adsf
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="options" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Options</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            The options
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- .col-md-4 -->
    </div><!-- .row -->
  </div><!-- .container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

all panels have to be in the same parent-div. thats why you've got that issue. This should fix it ;)

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs visible-xs visible-sm">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#info">Info</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#docs">Docs</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#updates">Updates</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contacts">Contacts</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#options">Options</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="info" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane active colOverrides col-md-8">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Info</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Info content
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="contacts" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane colOverrides col-md-4 ">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Contacts</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Contacts Stuff
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="docs" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane colOverrides col-md-8">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Docs</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Document Stuff
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="options" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane colOverrides col-md-4">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Options</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            The options
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="updates" role="tabpanel" class="panel panel-default tab-pane colOverrides col-md-8">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Updates</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Bunch of updates
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**And CSS:**

```
.tab-content .panel-heading {
    display: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .tab-content > .tab-pane {
        display: block;
    }
    .tab-content .panel-heading {
        display: block;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .colOverrides.col-md-8 {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
    .colOverrides.col-md-4 {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
}
.colOverrides {
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 15px;
}
.colOverrides.col-md-8 {
    width: calc(66.66666667% - 30px);
}
.colOverrides.col-md-4 {
    width: calc(33.33333333% - 30px);
}
```

---

Working solution: http://www.bootply.com/OzJJ2bX9ef

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks the column layout when you start adding content: http://www.bootply.com/Nb8qCoQ4eV